# CSV upload with concurrent REST queries maxes out CPU resources

Tags: csv, neo4j, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Neo4J 3.0.6 CE installed on a 2.4 GHz Xeon 4 core (with 8 threads) CPU in a VM with 24GB running on Windows Server 2012 r-2.

It runs fine with frequent (around 1-5 per second) updates via REST calls of client details applying for loans and logging on to an app. Total store size is 18.48 GiB at present with 46,741,582 relationships, 68,627,444 properties and 5,360,756 nodes.

Recently I wanted to delete a series of relationships as contained in a CSV with approximately 12m lines with this call:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///ClientCallLogs.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (c:Client {AtlasId: line.AtlasId})
      -[ud:`used deviceid`]->
      (devID:DeviceId {DID:line.DeviceId})
DELETE ud
```

Prior to this call I define indeces on Client and DeviceId like so:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Client(AtlasId)
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX ON :DeviceId(DID)
```

Changing

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 to USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
```

has no noticeable effect.

This call, however starts well but soon the CPUs max out and shortly after that the Neo4J process becomes unresponsive and starts throwing exceptions on further REST calls.  The only remedy then is to kill and restart the server  after which all is well again.

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [periodic commits](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data). For example every thousand lines:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:///ClientCallLogs.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (c:Client {AtlasId: line.AtlasId})
      -[ud:`used deviceid`]->
      (devID:DeviceId {DID:line.DeviceId})
DELETE ud
```

Be sure to use an index:

```
create index on :Client(AtlasId);
create index on :DeviceId(DeviceId);
```

Comment: @DisplayMyNameHere What about index for `:Client AtlasId` and `:DeviceId DeviceId`?

Comment: : I run the following: CREATE INDEX ON :DeviceId(DID) and CREATE INDEX ON :Client(AtlasId)